# Framework to create video-streamed 3D game

Tags: gratis, video, streaming, 3d

I have to develop a video-streamed game (a bit like OnLive). The 3D processing is done on a server and the resulting video is streamed to any client device.

The game has to be 3D but can be as simple as I want it to be (e.g. shooting stuff from a cannon). The preferred technologies are Ogre 3D + ffmpeg, and I did a lot of coding but it didn't work properly, so I gave up.

If no ready-to-use framework exists, could you recommend me the easiest coupling of technologies that could work? Maybe Unity can be video streamed?

Comment: Note that we don't recommend "technologies" or [code fragments](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/904/185), but **software** (ready-to-use). Asking for libraries is OK, but you'd need at least to specify the programming language you want to use.

Comment: KillerZefi, can we safely assume that you are OK with any programming language?

Comment: Yes, I'm OK with any language, though C++ is preferred.